# I have two php in my mac OS X, how can i eliminate one of them?

Tags: php, macos

Actually i have two php one in /usr/ which i can use and localhost/info.php is show this and the other one is /opt/local/ which is using by Command line.

How can i use one PHP in both places?

Thanks
Haroon

Comment: are you talking about the version you use on the commandline (aka: cli) versus the one your webserver (e.g. apache module) uses? Because that is a normal situation, as you cannot use a module version on the commandline, nor the CLI version in apache.

Comment: You'd place a symlink into /usr/bin I guess, so simply delete the one you don't use and make sure the other one is available (through a link) in /usr/bin.

Answer (score 0):

Add php path (that you want to use) to front of `$PATH` global variable in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Try add an alias: `alias php="/your/php/path/php"`